# How to encode '?' in url in springboot RestTemplate exchange method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, urlencode

I am building an application in springboot.
I have this block of code:

```
String testUrl = "http://example.com/filter1/filter2/Art: Is It Value?";
ExampleResources<Test> exampleResources =
                    restTemplate.exchange(testUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, new 
                    ParameterizedTypeReference<ExampleResources<Test>>() {
                    }).getBody();
```

It returns empty list. But if I do a GET request for the url in Postman I am getting the correct results. After testing for some time I found that the question mark("?") is causing issues. How should I deal with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

Comment: Try `"http://example.com/filter1/filter2/" + URLEncoder.encode("Art: Is It Value?", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: Using URI format instead of String solved the issue. I built the uri using UriComponentsBuilder().

Answer (score 1):

I think you can encode problematic part using URLEncoder.encode method.

Look at the below sample code.

```
String url = "http://example.com/filter1/filter2/";
String value = "Art: Is It Value?";
String newValue = URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
String newUrl = url + newValue;
```

So your newUrl will look like something below.

```
http://example.com/filter1/filter2/Art%3A+Is+It+Value%3F
```

See if that helps resolving your issue.